Want to Play Random Songs Continuously in P5
I am trying to create a sketch that will play a random song from an array on click, and will continue to pick a new random song on each click. I am unable to get any song to play at the moment.
Here is the code I have now, the current error I receive is 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isPlaying').
let sound, amplitude;
let R;
let x = 0;

function preload(){
  sound1 = loadSound('taptwice.mp3');
  sound2 = loadSound('juniper.mp3');
  sound3 = loadSound('eyelids.mp3');
}

function setup() {
  let cnv = createCanvas(windowWidth,windowHeight);
  cnv.mouseClicked(toggleSound);
  amplitude = new p5.Amplitude();
  let playlist = ['sound1', 'sound2', 'sound3'];
  let sound = playlist[Math.floor(Math.random()*playlist.length)];
  console.log(random,sound[random]);
}


function toggleSound() {
  if (sound.isPlaying() ){
    sound.stop();
  } else {
    sound.play();
  }
}


There are a few issues here. Always code slowly, validating every step. If you speed ahead too quickly, without verifying your code as you go, you'll wind up with numerous issues and it can be overwhelming to debug all of them at once.
To fix bugs, minimize the code and add debugging logs to figure out the problem. Remove unused variables which distract from the problem you're trying to solve.
To solve large problems, solve small problems first. Figure out how to play one song first, then build on that to play multiple songs.
In your code, when you use let sound =  inside the setup() function, the variable is scoped to that function only, and isn't accessible from toggleSound(), which only has access to the undefined outer scope sound. Fix the problem by removing let so the sound = ... assignment will bind to the outer sound.
Here's a cleaned up, runnable example:


const audioFiles = [
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a7/Audio_James_Randi_Long_Version.ogg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ed/Andrew_Dessler.ogg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7f/Bluetooth.ogg",
];
let sound;
let playlist;

function preload() {
  playlist = audioFiles.map(e => loadSound(e));
}

function setup() {
  const cnv = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  cnv.mouseClicked(toggleSound);
  sound = playlist[floor(random(0, playlist.length))];
}

function toggleSound() {
  if (sound.isPlaying()) {
    sound.stop();
  } else {
    sound.play();
  }
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.0/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>



Now, if you want to pick a different song on each click, move the random selection outside of setup and into the toggle:


const audioFiles = [
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a7/Audio_James_Randi_Long_Version.ogg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ed/Andrew_Dessler.ogg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7f/Bluetooth.ogg",
];
let sound;
let playlist;

function preload() {
  playlist = audioFiles.map(e => loadSound(e));
}

function setup() {
  const cnv = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  cnv.mouseClicked(toggleSound);
}

function toggleSound() {
  if (sound?.isPlaying()) {
    sound.stop();
  } else {
    sound = playlist[floor(random(0, playlist.length))];
    sound.play();
  }
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.0/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>




I really, really appreciate that you took the time to answer this. Thank you so much!
